# Custom column template for DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a DataTable.DefaultView, which renders the grid  using auto generation of columns. That part works fine. However, for some columns I would like to use a custom template. The problem is that columns in the table change on each load, so the solution needs to be generic.

I can hook into the AutoGeneratingColumn event as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but still have problem with defining the template binding:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="customCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ???"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

(...)

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultView}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
</DataGrid>
```

And my code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    string colName = e.PropertyName;
    if (someCondition)
    {
        var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        templateColumn.Header = colName;
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["customCellTemplate"];
        templateColumn.SortMemberPath = colName;
        e.Column = templateColumn;
     }
```

As you can see I don't know how to define the binding in the column template, because the column name changes.

**EDIT:**

In addition to the accepted answer - sometimes it's easier to create the entire template programmatically as described here:
http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2013/12/wpf-datagrid-custom-template-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `StaticResource` forces you to keep it the same -- remember, static means there's just one instance, so if you change its binding for one column, you will change it for all of them.  So it will have to be like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="customCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

I was thinking you could use this template in a dynamic way by wrapping it in another DataTemplate using a `ContentControl`.  Set the `Content` property dynamically, and use the static template for the `ContentTemplate`:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    string colName = e.PropertyName;
    if (someCondition)
    {
        string xaml = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><ContentControl Content=""{0}"" ContentTemplate=""{1}"" /></DataTemplate>";
        var tmpl = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(string.Format(xaml, "{Binding " + colName + "}", "{StaticResource customCellTemplate}"));
        var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = tmpl;
        templateColumn.Header = colName;
        templateColumn.SortMemberPath = colName;
        e.Column = templateColumn;
     }
}
```

The only catch is that, with this setup, I believe "customCellTemplate" will have to be defined at the application level.

Comment: This approach works, however I need to define this cell template on user control level, not application. The reason for that is that I'm developing a UserControl library, that will be reused by multiple applications. Any workaround for that?

Also, current code would not compile as the XamlReader.Load expects stream (easy fix).